# How to create active links with Mustache?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, hyperlink, mustache

How to create active clickable links with Mustache?
I prefer to use javascript version of Mustache for this.

In other words:

I want to autolink user generated text content with javascript/mustache (=linkify).

**Template**

```
{{#.}}
    <div>{{.}}</div>
{{/.}}
```

**Data**

```
[
    'User content, like regular text.',
    'User content with text and links http://www.google.com or secure https://www.google.com'
]
```

**Output I'm looking for**

```
<div>User content, like regular text.</div>
<div>User content with text and links <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> or secure <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use {{{.}}} instead of {{.}} - this will not escape special characters.

Comment: Welcome :) But if the content is generated by users, be careful not to render some undesired js script that can do bad things.