# How to render hyper link using mustach?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mustache

I am using mustach. This is my code:

```
const view = {
    googleLinkAddress: 'http://google.com',
  };
  const template = '<a href="{{{googleLinkAddress}}}">Google.com</a>';

  return Mustache.render(template, view);
```

On screen, it renders as a text literal

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
```

instead of of a link [Google.com](http://google.com)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a templating engine like Mustache when you already have Vue.js to render dynamic content?

Comment: There is need in the project

Comment: Got the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019029/how-to-create-active-links-with-mustache